# Buildfire - Do Buildfire Apps Stop Running When in the Background?

Tags: buildfire

I am currently doing a spec for a plugin that requires the ability to work while in the background.  This is a timer plugin, that would essentially allow people to set intervals of time and run through them automatically during their workouts.  During transition periods between these different intervals, there would be sounds and other things happening.

One of the requirements is that this app does not need to be in the forefront at all points in time while a user is in the middle of their workout.  I have looked in the documentation, but haven't really seen anything about plugins actually running in the background besides the calendar methods "Onbackgrounded" and "OnResumed", which will invoke some callback when those events are triggered.

This doesn't really help me as those events only fire when the app is in the foreground.  Are there any suggestions or insight you could provide me with to be able to implement this.  Have I overlooked something in the SDK wiki?

Answer (score 0):

By default apps don't run while they are in the background, although there are exceptions. For example BuildFire supports background audio and background geo location services. This is done via adding the appropriate [features](https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/Features-List) to your plugin. I don't believe there is a general purpose "run in background" feature, although it's possible that it could be added in the future.

Another option is to look into [local notifications](https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/Buildfire-Local-Notifications-API). They allow you to show the user a notification, based on an time passing.

```
var options = {
            title: 'Notification Title',
            text: 'Notification Body',
            data: {},
            at: sendTime,
            returnToPluginInstanceId: '' //optional
        };

        buildfire.notifications.localNotification.schedule(options, function (err, data) {
        });
```

Comment: Would a service worker be able to run in the background while the app was out of focus and be used to keep track of changes as if the app were focused, or would a service worker deactivate as well?

Comment: @tbergen1 Safari on iOS doesn't support service workers. Web workers do work across browsers, however that unfortunately doesn't address the situation. The reason being that without the necessary device permissions, the code won't run in the background. The main restriction is at the OS level.